# calling Faces Servlet root URL throws Nullpointer

Tags: jsf, servlets, websphere, myfaces

My web project's .war file has the context root `myapp/something` and it is defined in the `application.xml` of the EAR file.

In this project I have some Servlets that work fine with this. But now I added a Server Faces Servlet to the `web.xml` with the pattern `/Monitoring/mySite`.

The problem now is that if I call the URL `http://somehost/myapp/something/Monitoring/mySite` I end up in a NullPointer loop because there is no view available (known Websphere issue, [fix for that here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI38066)).
I thought by setting `web/page.xhtml` as the `welcome-file` in the `web.xml` this should be fixed, but it only applies to the context-root of the application, namely `/myapp/something`.

So what works is if I make the following calls:
`http://somehost/myapp/something/Monitoring/mySite/web/page.xhtml`
`http://somehost/myapp/something`

**TL;DR**

But I would like to see the `page.xhtml` when I call `http://somehost/myapp/something/Monitoring/mySite`.

How can I accomplish this?

**/TL;DR**

The following is the `web.xml` of the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="myProject" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>This is mySite</display-name>

<!-- Change to "Production" when you are ready to deploy -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Monitoring</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Monitoring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>some.path.to.Monitoring</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MonitoringExtended</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MonitoringExtended</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>some.path.to.MonitoringExtended</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>FacesServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Monitoring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Monitoring</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MonitoringExtended</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Monitoring/extended</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Monitoring/mysite/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>web/page.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>faces/web/page.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Here the part of my `application.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">

<display-name>myApplication</display-name>  

<module>
    <ejb>myApplication.jar</ejb>
</module>
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>myProject.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>myapp/something</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
</application>
```

Here the `ibm-web-ext.xml` (legacy, didn't touch it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappext:WebAppExtension xmi:version="2.0"
xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappext="webappext.xmi"
xmi:id="WebAppExtension_1229358884593" reloadInterval="3"
reloadingEnabled="true" additionalClassPath="" fileServingEnabled="true"
directoryBrowsingEnabled="false" serveServletsByClassnameEnabled="true">
    <webApp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID" />
</webappext:WebAppExtension>
```

And finally the `ibm-web-bnd.xml`(also legacy, didn't touch it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<webappbnd:WebAppBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:webappbnd="webappbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WebAppBinding_123456789" virtualHostName="default_host">
     <webapp href="WEB-INF/web.xml#WebApp_ID"/>
</webappbnd:WebAppBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a workaround.

What I did is a URL pattern to my `page.xhtml`, but renamed so it would fit my needs, like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Monitoring/mySite.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this I need a new folder **Monitoring** in my **WebContent** folder (for other project I guess it's the **webapp** folder). There I would place my `mySite.xhtml`.

Now I can call `http://somehost/myapp/something/Monitoring/mySite.xhtml`.
Not quite the solution I hoped for (I would like to eliminate the .xhtml), but it works.

And with this I also don't run into the Nullpointer loop bug, because there is no URL pattern that would create it.